# ios - CommonCrypto - does CCCrypt only works two time?

Tags: ios, cryptography

I'm using CCCrypt and it getting my nerve.

I don't know why, if i call multiple time the same function, it works only two times, then after it doesn't work anymore.

Why i don't understand is that the documentation says that it is stateless, but that's not acting like it is stateless. Here the code:

```
- (NSData *) cryptOperation:(CCOperation)operation withKey:(NSString *)keyStr
                      andIV: (NSString *)iv {

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char key[kCCKeySizeAES256];
    [keyStr getCString:key maxLength:sizeof(key) encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

    // Perform PKCS7Padding on the key.
    unsigned long bytes_to_pad = sizeof(key) - [keyStr length];
    if (bytes_to_pad > 0) {
        char byte = bytes_to_pad;
        for (unsigned long i = sizeof(key) - bytes_to_pad; i < sizeof(key); i++)
            key[i] = byte;
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(operation, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     key, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     [iv UTF8String],
                                     [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                     buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                     &numBytesDecrypted);

    NSLog(@"get %lu %lu %p %u", bufferSize, numBytesDecrypted, self, kCCSuccess);
    if (status == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of buffer and will free it on dealloc
        return [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

And here is my test:

```
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    [self cryptOperation:kCCDecrypt withKey:key andIV:nil]; // will works
    [self cryptOperation:kCCDecrypt withKey:key andIV:nil]; // will works
    [self cryptOperation:kCCDecrypt withKey:key andIV:nil]; // will not works!
    [self cryptOperation:kCCDecrypt withKey:key andIV:nil]; // same

    return [self cryptOperation:kCCDecrypt withKey:key andIV:nil]; // same
}
```

It is a category of NSData, and it work well. But what strange is that it only work two time. If I try to copy a NSData and call the method, that will be the same. It will only work two time. No matter which NSData calling it.

Can someone could help me? cause i really don't get it.

*** EDIT ***

I totally give up using this code. Instead i use a more robust library.

I totally gave up when i see that CCCrypt change the result depending of what kind of instructions is **after** the CCCrypt call. That's totally strange.

for example

```
 CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(operation, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     key, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     [iv UTF8String],
                                     [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                     buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                     &numBytesDecrypted);

    NSLog(@"get %lu %lu %p %u", bufferSize, numBytesDecrypted, self, kCCSuccess);
// numBytesDecrypted will always be 0 size!!!

return nil;
```

Depending on where the "return" instruction is and what it returns, the result of CCrypt is totally different 0_0, how could that be? Haven't checked the raw instruction, so i can't make strong assumption about this, but I strongly suspect Clang doing strange stuff, even with no ARC mode enabled. And to be honest i'm not an assembler genius -_-. That's to weird for me.

Comment: Haha! I laughed when I read this. Usually its a programming error. But the folks in Cupertino clearly don't test their software, so who knows....